# ResourceAccessException when trying to login into the application

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am facing the below exception when trying to login into the application.

Exception:

```
2016-08-11 14:06:18,698 ERROR [com.myApp.auto.servicing.UserRestClient] Unable to update user logged in information
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Default SSL context init failed: null; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Default SSL context init failed: null
```

UserRestClient.java

```
void sendUserLoggedInformation(String userKey)
{
    if ("null".equals(userKey))
    {
        return;
    }
    final String url =
        AbstractDAOFactory.getDAOFactory().getAutoServicesURLDAO()
            .getAutoServiceURL(AutoServicingURLEnum.USER_LOGON_URL.getAutoServicingURLKey());
    try
    {
         getTemplate().postForLocation(url, null, userKey);
    }
    catch (RestClientException e)
    {
        logger.error("Unable to update user logged in information", e);
    }
}
```

I could not able to figure it out why the exception is generated at the below mentioned method when postForLocation(..) is invoked.Please suggest.

Comment: It seems you use a certificate for your server.

Comment: Configure the keystore and truststore properly and that should resolve the problem.

Comment: @rockcode, how to configure keystore and truststore? Suggestions would be helpful. Thanks